# How to add new Linux user restricted to ssh tunneling with password?

Tags: linux, ssh

I wanted to create a new user on my linux server so that he can access my postgres database through an ssh tunnel. However, I want him to restrict his access only to the ssh tunnel.

I followed these steps:

1. login on server as `root`
2. Create a new user with `useradd new_user -M -s /bin/true`
3. Set a password with `passwd new_user`
4. make sure that `PasswordAuthentication yes` is set and uncomment in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
5. Restart ssh with `sudo systemctl reload sshd`
6. Logout from server and login to server with new user with `ssh -p 7822 new_user@my_address.com -N 5433:localhost:5432` (I am using a2hosting as a provider, where I need to use port 7822 for ssh)

However, when I try to login I get the error

> Permission denied, please try again.

When I do everything like above but change step 2 into

`useradd new_user -m -d /home/new_user`

I can successfully login with the new user, however, I then have the possibility to actually access command line, which I try to avoid. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try using /bin/false instead.

Comment: @RamanSailopal Great! That solved it for me! Please add your reply as an official answer (perhaps with a little explanation why the change had to be made) so I can accept it.

Comment: That's not a programming question and more suitable for superuser.com. There, make sure you read the site guidelines and the descriptions of the tags that you apply, please!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could be that /bin/true is not available on the system. As an alternative, use the alternate /bin/false.

Both perform the same function but /bin/false tends to be used more.

Answer (score 0):

Where `/bin/true` and `/bin/false` are not available, you can also use `/usr/sbin/nologin`. Recent versions of Ubuntu apply here.

```
useradd new_user -M -s /usr/sbin/nologin
```

A further aside is that for automated tunnels (for example, in reverse tunnelling scenarios) no password is required for the user and authentication can be handled with public/private keys.